# angular 4 call component method when re-routing to it

Tags: angular, components, angular-routing, angular4-router

I have a routing strategy that does not destroy the component when routing to another component. I would like to call a method of the component, when (re)routing to it.

Until now I've tried implementing the interfaces `AfterContentChecked` and `AfteViewChecked` with their respective methods `ngAfterContentChecked` and `ngAfterViewChecked. The only problem with implementing one of this interfaces is that the method is called multiple times when routing to the component and this is a performance problem for me.

While researching the web I haven't come across an interface which I could implement in order to obtain the desired behaviour.

Is the only possibility for solving this, verifying in the router which route/path was selected and in the case of the desired one, I call the method of the component?

Comment: You can put into `ngOnInit()` function.

Comment: @SunilSingh no I can't, because `ngOnInit()` is called only once, after the component was initialised, but if I reroute to an existing component, then the `ngOnInit` won't be called again. I tried it.

Comment: You can subscribe to the router's events, which will fire whenever a route change happens. This way you can check in your component if the current route is eed your component's route and execute whatever method you need

Comment: You might want to have a look at **[`Router Events`](https://angular.io/api/router/Event)**

Comment: @Robin-Hoodie your proposed solution works perfectly. Post the solution as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Paul, I've added some implementation detail that you might want to have a look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the [router](https://angular.io/api/router)'s [events](https://angular.io/api/router/Event), this will fire off an event each time your route changes. You can then get the active route of off this event and check if the route of the component you're currently in is equal to that route.

TIP: Filter on the events by using `instanceof NavigationEnd`

Answer (score 1):

You can basically add inject `Router` as a dependency and then subscribe to `events` on it. There is a list of **[`events`](https://angular.io/api/router/Event)** that Router exposes.

Since we only care about the `NavigationEnd` event, you can filter that out using the `filter` operator.

The event data has a `url` property that can be used to compare with the path that was attained after `NavigationEnd`

```
this.router.events
.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
)
.subscribe((event: any) => {
  console.log('Got the Event URL as '. event.url);
})
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uri-encode-activated-route-param?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproject%2Fproject.component.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever routing happens Component get created and `ngOnInit` function is called.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(){
     //called first time before the ngOnInit()
  }

  ngOnInit(){
     //called after the constructor
  }
}
```

Other two options that we have are -

1. `Resover` - `resolve` function
2. `Gaurds` - `canActive` function

`Resolver` and `Gaurd` get executed whenever routing is changing.

Comment: I said in my question, that I'm using a routing strategy which does not destroy the component, therefore it reuses the already created components.

Comment: Other two options that we have are `Resover` and `Gaurds`.  Resolver and Gaurd get executed whenever routing is changing.